# How to find percentage of maximum of groups across multiple variable columns

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tidyverse, sapply

I have a dataset `df` that looks like this:

```
Experiment Ch1    Ch2     Ch3     Ch4
exp_1   -1548   -19296  -65764  -64392
exp_1   -1572   -19304  -65756  -64392
exp_1   -1588   -19284  -65748  -64400
exp_1   -1580   -19292  -65760  -64392
exp_1   -1584   -19292  -65744  -64388
exp_1   -1580   -19292  -65756  -64408
exp_1   -1612   -19280  -65748  -64428
exp_2   -1620   -19276  -65740  -64464
exp_2   -1632   -19272  -65728  -64452
exp_2   -1636   -19268  -65732  -64464
exp_2   -1644   -19260  -65728  -64476
exp_2   -1652   -19268  -65736  -64476
exp_2   -1652   -19292  -65728  -64484
exp_2   -1660   -19268  -65740  -64480
exp_2   -1648   -19276  -65736  -64492
exp_3   -1664   -19276  -65736  -64504
exp_3   -1672   -19260  -65752  -64496
exp_3   -1668   -19276  -65728  -64496
exp_3   -1684   -19272  -65732  -64476
exp_3   -1676   -19260  -65728  -64476
exp_3   -1672   -19264  -65716  -64492
exp_3   -1680   -19268  -65732  -64480
exp_3   -1668   -19276  -65728  -64496
exp_3   -1684   -19272  -65732  -64476
```

I would like to produce columns that show a percentage of maximum for each group of my values based on the corresponding "Experiment number".

Such as this:

```
Experiment Ch1  %.Ch1    Ch2    %.Ch2    Ch3    %.Ch3    Ch4    %.Ch4
exp_1   -1548   100.00  -19296  99.92   -65764  99.97   -64392  99.99
exp_1   -1572   98.47   -19304  99.88   -65756  99.98   -64392  99.99
exp_1   -1588   97.48   -19284  99.98   -65748  99.99   -64400  99.98
exp_1   -1580   97.97   -19292  99.94   -65760  99.98   -64392  99.99
exp_1   -1584   97.73   -19292  99.94   -65744  100.00  -64388  100.00
exp_1   -1580   97.97   -19292  99.94   -65756  99.98   -64408  99.97
exp_1   -1612   96.03   -19280  100.00  -65748  99.99   -64428  99.94
exp_2   -1620   100.00  -19276  99.92   -65740  99.98   -64464  99.98
exp_2   -1632   99.26   -19272  99.94   -65728  100.00  -64452  100.00
exp_2   -1636   99.02   -19268  99.96   -65732  99.99   -64464  99.98
exp_2   -1644   98.54   -19260  100.00  -65728  100.00  -64476  99.96
exp_2   -1652   98.06   -19268  99.96   -65736  99.99   -64476  99.96
exp_2   -1652   98.06   -19292  99.83   -65728  100.00  -64484  99.95
exp_2   -1660   97.59   -19268  99.96   -65740  99.98   -64480  99.96
exp_2   -1648   98.30   -19276  99.92   -65736  99.99   -64492  99.94
exp_3   -1664   100.00  -19276  99.92   -65736  99.97   -64504  99.96
exp_3   -1672   99.52   -19260  100.00  -65752  99.95   -64496  99.97
exp_3   -1668   99.76   -19276  99.92   -65728  99.98   -64496  99.97
exp_3   -1684   98.81   -19272  99.94   -65732  99.98   -64476  100.00
exp_3   -1676   99.28   -19260  100.00  -65728  99.98   -64476  100.00
exp_3   -1672   99.52   -19264  99.98   -65716  100.00  -64492  99.98
exp_3   -1680   99.05   -19268  99.96   -65732  99.98   -64480  99.99
exp_3   -1668   99.76   -19276  99.92   -65728  99.98   -64496  99.97
exp_3   -1684   98.81   -19272  99.94   -65732  99.98   -64476  100.00
```

I know that the solution likely can be accomplished with Base R, or dplyr's group_by function, but I am stuck on how to do multiple columns at once. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Experiment) %>% mutate_at(vars(contains("Ch")), .funs = list(
  PCT = function(x) {
    round((max(x) / x) * 100, 2)
  }
))
```

Mutate at columns with names which contains `"Ch"`. Putting the function in the mutate call as a list allows you to append an identifier to the column names you're mutating to create new columns.

Actual figures are only rounded to two digits if you use `View(df)`.

```
   Experiment   Ch1    Ch2    Ch3    Ch4 Ch1_PCT Ch2_PCT Ch3_PCT Ch4_PCT
   <fct>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 exp_1      -1548 -19296 -65764 -64392   100      99.9    100.   100. 
 2 exp_1      -1572 -19304 -65756 -64392    98.5    99.9    100.   100. 
 3 exp_1      -1588 -19284 -65748 -64400    97.5   100.     100.   100. 
 4 exp_1      -1580 -19292 -65760 -64392    98.0    99.9    100.   100. 
 5 exp_1      -1584 -19292 -65744 -64388    97.7    99.9    100    100  
 6 exp_1      -1580 -19292 -65756 -64408    98.0    99.9    100.   100. 
 7 exp_1      -1612 -19280 -65748 -64428    96.0   100      100.    99.9
 8 exp_2      -1620 -19276 -65740 -64464   100      99.9    100.   100. 
 9 exp_2      -1632 -19272 -65728 -64452    99.3    99.9    100    100  
10 exp_2      -1636 -19268 -65732 -64464    99.0   100.     100.   100. 
11 exp_2      -1644 -19260 -65728 -64476    98.5   100      100    100. 
12 exp_2      -1652 -19268 -65736 -64476    98.1   100.     100.   100. 
13 exp_2      -1652 -19292 -65728 -64484    98.1    99.8    100    100. 
14 exp_2      -1660 -19268 -65740 -64480    97.6   100.     100.   100. 
15 exp_2      -1648 -19276 -65736 -64492    98.3    99.9    100.    99.9
16 exp_3      -1664 -19276 -65736 -64504   100      99.9    100.   100. 
17 exp_3      -1672 -19260 -65752 -64496    99.5   100      100.   100. 
18 exp_3      -1668 -19276 -65728 -64496    99.8    99.9    100.   100. 
19 exp_3      -1684 -19272 -65732 -64476    98.8    99.9    100.   100  
20 exp_3      -1676 -19260 -65728 -64476    99.3   100      100.   100  
21 exp_3      -1672 -19264 -65716 -64492    99.5   100.     100    100. 
22 exp_3      -1680 -19268 -65732 -64480    99.0   100.     100.   100. 
23 exp_3      -1668 -19276 -65728 -64496    99.8    99.9    100.   100. 
24 exp_3      -1684 -19272 -65732 -64476    98.8    99.9    100.   100
```

Then later sort the columns by:

```
df %>% select(Experiment, names(df)[-1] %>% sort())

   Experiment   Ch1 Ch1_PCT    Ch2 Ch2_PCT    Ch3 Ch3_PCT    Ch4 Ch4_PCT
   <fct>      <int>   <dbl>  <int>   <dbl>  <int>   <dbl>  <int>   <dbl>
 1 exp_1      -1548   100   -19296    99.9 -65764    100. -64392   100. 
 2 exp_1      -1572    98.5 -19304    99.9 -65756    100. -64392   100. 
 3 exp_1      -1588    97.5 -19284   100.  -65748    100. -64400   100. 
 4 exp_1      -1580    98.0 -19292    99.9 -65760    100. -64392   100. 
 5 exp_1      -1584    97.7 -19292    99.9 -65744    100  -64388   100  
 6 exp_1      -1580    98.0 -19292    99.9 -65756    100. -64408   100. 
 7 exp_1      -1612    96.0 -19280   100   -65748    100. -64428    99.9
 8 exp_2      -1620   100   -19276    99.9 -65740    100. -64464   100. 
 9 exp_2      -1632    99.3 -19272    99.9 -65728    100  -64452   100  
10 exp_2      -1636    99.0 -19268   100.  -65732    100. -64464   100. 
11 exp_2      -1644    98.5 -19260   100   -65728    100  -64476   100. 
12 exp_2      -1652    98.1 -19268   100.  -65736    100. -64476   100. 
13 exp_2      -1652    98.1 -19292    99.8 -65728    100  -64484   100. 
14 exp_2      -1660    97.6 -19268   100.  -65740    100. -64480   100. 
15 exp_2      -1648    98.3 -19276    99.9 -65736    100. -64492    99.9
16 exp_3      -1664   100   -19276    99.9 -65736    100. -64504   100. 
17 exp_3      -1672    99.5 -19260   100   -65752    100. -64496   100. 
18 exp_3      -1668    99.8 -19276    99.9 -65728    100. -64496   100. 
19 exp_3      -1684    98.8 -19272    99.9 -65732    100. -64476   100  
20 exp_3      -1676    99.3 -19260   100   -65728    100. -64476   100  
21 exp_3      -1672    99.5 -19264   100.  -65716    100  -64492   100. 
22 exp_3      -1680    99.0 -19268   100.  -65732    100. -64480   100. 
23 exp_3      -1668    99.8 -19276    99.9 -65728    100. -64496   100. 
24 exp_3      -1684    98.8 -19272    99.9 -65732    100. -64476   100
```